# Relation aggregate using /n as concatenator?

Tags: qgis

```
relation_aggregate(
    'S1Structur_SD_Sondages20_Num',
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    expression:="description_us",
    concatenator:='\n'
)
```

I want to use a linebreaker as concatenator.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, `\n` is a character like an other, so it will work.

Comment: thanks! subject is closed!